# Pages: prevent multiple adjacent hyphens

Tags: pages, font, keyboard

Usually it is considered bad typography to have more than two (?) lines in a row ending with a hyphen. I just wrote a paragraph in Pages and ended up with four adjacent hyphenated lines. Ugly!

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I'd recast a sentence if you can. One word of a different length could push all hyphens away. Otherwise you're going to have to get aggressive with kerning/leading, which could get messy.

Comment: @Tetsujin Framemaker used to have a setting for this. I miss Framemaker a lot:-(

Comment: I used to work in QuarkExpress, which could similarly cleverly shuffle things like this. I haven't used 'real' page layout software in 20 years, though.